# Enabling word wrap

Tags: javascript, css, word-wrap

I am trying to convert HTML to PDF with jsPDF. But since I want every word to in the exact location as in HTML, I wrapped every word in `<span>`s. Here I have a `font` tag (not generated by my code) containing a bunch of `span`s:

```
<font><span>Hello</span>&nbsp;<span>wrap</span>&nbsp;<span>....</font>
```

However when I do this it seems to break the default wordwrapping as you can see in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/2HhTL/).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not exactly related however I recommend you don't use font tags anymore. CSS is the best way to do that now.
**EDIT** Just noticed you said you didn't generate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because default display is [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements). If you use `inline-block` it will wrap as you expect:

See this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HhTL/2/)**

The only change is to the CSS:

```
span
{
    display:inline-block;    
}
```

You may want to create a new class for this (e.g. `wordWrapSpan`) rather than changing default behaviour of span.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

style word-wrap: break-word;

`.font{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}`
See this fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HhTL/3/)